# How can I create and add n variables of type struct to a set?

Tags: c++, struct, set

I have a structure `node`, with `label` and `cost`.
I would like to insert a `node` into a `set` for `n` times, each node having the label `n`.

```
struct node
{
    int label;
    int cost;
};
set <node> Q;
node *a;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {   a=new node;
        (*a).label=i;
        (*a).cost=LONG_MAX;
        Q.insert(*a);
    }
```

Somehow when I build and run it I still only get one variable in my set. What did I do wrong?

```
struct node
{
    int label;
    int cost;
    bool operator < (const node &other) const { return cost < other.cost; }
    bool operator == (const node &other) const { return label < other.label; }
}; 
I'm not sure if that is correct.
```

(SOLVED)
how my loop looks like now:

```
multiset <node> Q; //instead of set <node> Q;

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            node a;
            a.label=i;
            a.cost=LONG_MAX;
            Q.insert(a);
        }
```

Comment: A `set` will only hold unique elements, not duplicates.  What does your comparison function (`operator <`) for `node` look like?

Comment: struct node
{
    int label;
    int cost;
    bool operator < (const node &other) const { return cost < other.cost; }
    bool operator == (const node &other) const { return label < other.label; }
}; 
I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: don't know if it is the cause of your error (need the real data), but it is logically inconsistent to use label field for equality and cost field for less-than.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you're leaking memory here.  There's no reason to use `new`.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Do you want to show a *comparison* function at least?

Answer (score 0):

The nodes you're adding all have the same cost, which is what you're using as the sort key.  A `set` will only store unique elements, so you only get one element for a particular cost.  If you want to store multiple elements with the same cost you should use a `multiset` instead.

Comment: How did you conclude that `cost` is being used as the sort key?

Comment: @BatCoder It is in his reply to my comment on the question.  It should be edited into the question rather then being left in a comment.